# How to modify partial, depending on controller it's viewed from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uiviewcontroller, view

I'm using a partial from my "messages" controller in my "tags" controller. The portion in question looks like this:

```
  <% unless message.tag_list.nil? || message.tag_list.empty? %>
    <% message.tags.each do |t| %>
      <div class="tag"><%= link_to t.name.titleize, tag_path(t) %></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Is there a way to hide this portion of the partial only when it is viewed from the "tags" controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<% unless controller.controller_name.eql?("tags") %>
   will only show if controller is NOT tags 
<% end %>
```

:) hope that helps!

Comment: and `controller.action_name` is there as well should you need it.